# How do I render and edit SVG data in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

Let's say that I have an SVG file in my database:

```
<svg width="400" height="100"> 
  <rect width="400" height="100" 
  style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /> 
</svg>
```

It looks like this
[image]

And in my React code I fetch the SVG file like so:

```
fetch('/api/picture')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      picture: res
    })
  })
```

So now in my state, I have a variable called picture whose value is this:

```
<svg width="400" height="100"> 
  <rect width="400" height="100" 
  style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /> 
</svg>
```

After doing some research, the only way that I have found to render the SVG is this way:

```
<div>
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.picture }}></div>
</div>
```

But I'm a little confused on whether this is the preferred and flexible way to do it.
If I want a button on my page where if I click it, the circle will turn red, how will I be able to do that with my current code? What about a button that will add another circle to the svg?

I know I have to access the rect in some way and change the style, but I cannot think of a way with the way I've set it up.

I tried looking for a solution but I can't seem to find one, so I'm under the impression that I have to render my SVG a different way. Could anyone help me figure this out? Thank you

Comment: [react-svg](https://github.com/tanem/react-svg) looks like a good choice to solve this. Another strategy, if you can do this already during the compilation process, would be to convert all your SVGs to components you can then import. Check out [svg-react-loader](https://github.com/jhamlet/svg-react-loader) or [svgr](https://react-svgr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created https://github.com/hugozap/react-svgmt to facilitate SVG loading and manipulation:

You can load the SVG from a url or string and use SvgProxy to
update any element using a CSS selector.

```
<SvgLoader width="100" height="100" path="/sample1.svg">
        <SvgProxy selector="rect" fill="red" />
</SvgLoader>
```

If you are interested I wrote an article about it sometime ago

https://medium.com/@hugozap/svg-manipulation-tools-for-react-e1d58b754c81

Comment: Hi, thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Just one thing though: If I wanted to add text to a square, how would I do so using react-svgmt?

Comment: You must add the text object and then you can set the Proxy contents and it will replace the text element content.

Comment: Yeah, I figured so. I did just that. Thank you!